# How do I make my player with a Rigidbody move with isKinematic checked?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My game is a topdown zombie shooter and whenever the zombies get to the player they bunch up underneath them, to the point where the player can just walk over the zombies. I noticed that when I check isKinematic on the Rigidbody the zombies cant push the player up to go underneath him, so they just run into him(which is what I want). Despite this I am then unable to move. How can i fix this?

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PlayerMoving1 : MonoBehaviour {
    public float moveSpeed;
    private Rigidbody myRigidbody;
    private Vector3 moveInput;
    private Vector3 moveVelocity;
    private Camera mainCamera;
    public GunController theGun;
      void Start () {
         myRigidbody = GetComponent <Rigidbody>();
        mainCamera = FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
     }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    moveInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    moveVelocity = moveInput * moveSpeed;
    Ray cameraRay = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    Plane groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
    float rayLength;
    if(groundPlane.Raycast(cameraRay,out rayLength))
    {
        Vector3 pointToLook = cameraRay.GetPoint(rayLength);
        transform.LookAt(new Vector3(pointToLook.x,transform.position.y,pointToLook.z));
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        theGun.isFiring = true;
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        theGun.isFiring = false;
}
void FixedUpdate(){
    myRigidbody.velocity = moveVelocity;
}
}
```

Comment: `isKinematic` is doing its job. Why do you need it to be enabled in the first place?

Comment: Well, when your player is completely surrounded by zombies, i wouldn't think he should be able to move. That being said, try increasing your player's mass. With more mass, his velocity should count for more when pushing against zombies.

Comment: because the zombies bunch up underneath the player instead of just pushing/running into him. I know isKinematic is doing its job but the problem is that I cant move while it is checked.

Comment: the same thing happens even if i increase the players mass

Comment: My comment totally neglected your "iskinematic" situation. Your player script won't make your player move at all with that enabled because the physics engine will essentially ignore anything with "iskinematic" enabled. Which means your script adding force does nothing. That is generally only reserved for static items like platforms, and floors/walls and such. So if you MUST have it checked, you'd have to modify your script to handle manipulating the transform position manually.

Comment: @oxrock how do i do that?

Comment: Why you don't sume the zombies mass to the player mass??

As a result you have a "only player weight from 1 mass", player+1 zombie=2 masses.....So till the player doesn't move

Answer (score 0):

With `isKinematic == true` You can't change object position through rigidbody, You can only change `transform.position`.

I think it could be better, if You set isKinematic to false and add stopping distance to enemies, so they can't get too close to player.

Answer (score 0):

Being that your player can no longer be effected by the physics engine, you'd have to manipulate the object's transform manually. Your script isn't ideally setup for it currently, but if I was to hack it into it and try to make it work it would look something like this:

(you can change it from fixedUpdate to update if you're no longer utilizing the physics engine)

```
void update(){
    float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")* Time.Deltatime;
    float z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * Time.Deltatime;
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x+x,0,transform.position.z+z);
```

Comment: I would also suggest adding an additional speed multiplier to add to those numbers and playing with it until it felt right to you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is to lock the position of Y for the player (assuming Y is the positive "up" direction). `isKinimatic` is best when you want to move the player or objects around yourself.

I would say upping the `mass` is better in this case, and you can keep `isKinematic` unchecked in this case then too. Also apply the lock for Y movement (again if it is the "up" direction from the plane)

Let me know what your solution is regardless, I've had some issues in the past as well with these types of events happening